# Dynamic linking or dynamic loading for shared libraries?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I can't know which solution is best in my situation to link a module to a binary. Either by dynamic linking or by dynamic loading with the DL API.

Knowing that :

1. we can specify a flag for the compilation that indicates whether you want to use or not the functions of the library to link (we can do #ifndef MODULE for example).
2. the library functions are used only once during runtime.

Don't hesitate if need additional information.

Comment: Dynamic loading only makes sense if your program can function without the library.

Comment: Are the library functions used only at the start of the program? Could you, for example, run your library functions as a executable and then replace the process using `exec()` to run the main application (taking the relevant info with you in the form of params)?

Comment: Too broad. Try to post an example and specify what you mean with _best_: in terms of what?

Comment: Dynamic *loading* serves the scenario in which the program does not know what library it needs until run time.  It provides for implementation of plugin-style functionality.  If you know in advance what library will be needed, then dynamic *linking* is almost surely the better alternative.

Comment: @Siguza the program can work without the library (libkrb5.so). As I said we can choose not to use it before the compilation.

Comment: @LPs By "best" I mean the most appropriate solution for the program given the two points I have listed.

Comment: @Galik the library (libkrb5.so) is only used at the start of the program to authenticate a session before connection.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the program knows whether or not it needs the library before the compilation, so at run time too. If the flag is set the program will use the library. If not no need of the library.

Comment: So if I'm right I have two different viewpoints. For @Siguza it makes sense to use dynamic loading because the program can work without the library. But for John Bollinger dynamic linking is the better alternative because I know in advance whether or not the library will be needed.

Comment: @Siguza's argument and mine are compatible, and in a sense they are the same.  If the program knows what library it needs before run time (i.e. at build time), then it is much easier and more conventional to call the library's functions directly, instead of indirectly via `dlsym()`.  Such calls can be suppressed via conditional compilation directives when the program is configured at build time to not use the lib.  If you do use direct calls then your program cannot function without the library -- not even for a run that doesn't actually call the library's functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your best answer is "it depends".

For example, if your platform has a plethora of memory available, then loading all external libraries before execution makes sense.

If loading all the libraries into memory at the beginning takes a lot of time, you may want to load libraries into memory on demand.

If the platform doesn't have a lot of memory, on demand loading makes more sense (don't load infrequently used libraries and keep in memory).

You may want to consider frequency of function usage before packaging into DLLs.